# How to avoid compiler errors while converting templates to arbitrary types

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use templates to read an image with arbitrary `std::vector` type as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Reader
{
    public:
        static void readShorts(string path, vector<short>& buffer)
        {
            // read short buffer
        }

        static void readChars(string path, vector<char>& buffer)
        {
            // read char buffer
        }
};

template <typename T>
class GenericReader
{
    public:
        static void read(string path, T& buffer)
        {
            if (typeid(buffer) == typeid(vector<char>))
            {
                Reader::readChars(path, buffer);
            }
            else if (typeid(buffer) == typeid(vector<short>))
            {
                Reader::readShorts(path, buffer);
            }
        }
};

template <typename T>
class Container
{
    private:
        map<int, T> images;

    public:
        void readImage(string path, int imageId)
        {
            GenericReader<T>::read(path, images[imageId]);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Container<vector<char>> container;
    container.readImage("some/path/img.tif", 0);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error C2664 : 'void Reader::readShorts(std::string,std::vector<short,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'T' to 'std::vector<short,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
```

I understand that the problem occurs because I created an object of the `Container` class with the `vector<char>` type, so eventually the `readShorts` member function of `Reader` gets called. But isn't that the purpose of using templates? I was thinking that I would get a runtime error in this case instead of a compiler error.

The second part of my question is, is there an elegant way to do what I'm trying to achieve here? I'm open to different approaches if I'm doing something terribly wrong.

*By the way I'm aware that the question title is not very clear so feel free to edit it.*

Comment: I see most of your SO activity so far is about Java. Don't fall into the trap of thinking that Java generics and C++ templates work in remotely the same way: they have nothing in common apart from the `<>` syntax. In particular, templates are an exclusively compile-time construct, which is why trying to mix them with `if`/`typeid` runtime logic doesn't work. Lookup `if constexpr` and `std::is_same`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `GenericReader` isn't generic at all (since it only works on two specific types), and just delegates to a specific implementation, a much easier way is to simply use overloading:

```
void readVector(string path, vector<short>& buffer)
{
    // read short buffer
}

void readVector(string path, vector<char>& buffer)
{
    // read char buffer
}
```

And then:

```
void readImage(string path, int imageId)
{
    readVector(path, images[imageId]);
}
```